# Ghidra Decompiler Optimized Strings

Tags: x86, ghidra, stack, decompiler

Looking at a large x86 binary, I'm seeing lots of instances where strings are assembled on the stack as quadwords like so:

[image: original decompiled output]

If I try to set the type of `puStack40` to `char[38]`, I get the following output that's still not very helpful:

[image: final decompiled output]

I am guessing that this is because each quadword is moved in a separate instruction:

[image: assembly]

I assume there isn't, but does anyone know of a way that I can get `puStack40` to be displayed as a string in the decompiler window?

(As a side note: why is this approach taken? My only guess would be to decrease the number of memory accesses. I don't think this is obfuscation since it's a large, commercial application)

Comment: Can you post the actual text (formatted as `code`) instead of images?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/0x6d696368/ghidra_scripts/blob/master/SearchSimpleStackStrings.md
https://github.com/0x6d696368/ghidra_scripts/blob/master/SimpleStackStrings.md

The only difference looks like search vs at current cursor position

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm asking if there's a way to set the data types such that there is a char array on the stack. The script(s) you linked only set comments as to what the strings are. I'm thinking I'll have to patch the program to accomplish this